Before function flow is not finished yet and setState update is not done, get latest state for debugging purpose
Is there any chance to see updated state before function flow is not finished in React for debugging purpose.
function a = () => {
   ....statements
   setState(a);
   ....statements
   {here can I know what is a value in state before finishing a scope}
}


Do you want to know what was the previous value or the updated value?


{here can I know what is a value in state before finishing a scope}

As you know already, by design React works on Batching. Meaning React processes state updaters only after finishing the running event handler. This also means that the state updaters within an event handler, do not instantly change its current values, instead it just request for a new render.
Still we can deduce the new state as below:
Your original code
function a = () => {
   ....statements
   setState(a);
   ....statements
   {here can I know what is a value in state before finishing a scope}
}


If a in the above code is either a const or an expression, then the new state value will be a itself.

if a is an updater function, then the new value can be deduced by invoking the same updater function by passing the present state value. The result will be the new state value.


Please see the code below which demoes the same. The output of the test runs have also been attached.
App.js
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function App() {

  const [number1, setNumber1] = useState(0);
  const [number2, setNumber2] = useState(1);

  function handleClick(e) {

    setNumber1(number1 + 1);
    setNumber2((number2) => number2 * 10);

    console.log(`Previous render: deduced values`);
    console.log(`number1 : ${number1 + 1} `);
    console.log(`number2 : ${((prevNumber2) => prevNumber2 * 10)(number2)} `);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <label>Latest render : actual values</label>
      <br />
      <label>number1 : {number1}</label>
      <br />
      <label>number2 : {number2}</label>
      <br />
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Change State</button>
    </>
  );
}

Test run results:
1st click on Change state - Browser and Console display

2nd click on Change state - Browser and Console display

Citations:
State as a Snapshot
Queueing a Series of State Updates
